# how to create static cursor in db2?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2

I am facing a problem while creating a static cursor in DB2. This is the statement i used in my SP.

```
DECLARE CURNAME SENSITIVE STATIC SCROLL CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT COL1, COL2 
        FROM SCH.TABLENA 
        ORDER BY COL1;
```

on compilation it says : 
*DB2 Database Error: ERROR [42601] [IBM][DB2/NT] SQL0104N  An unexpected token "SENSITIVE" was found following "".  Expected tokens may include:  "FOR".  LINE NUMBER=20.  SQLSTATE=42601*

The version of Db2 i am using is 9.5.

Please let me know how to create a Static cursor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you are declaring the cursor in an SP. Here's the syntax for the same:

```
>>-DECLARE--cursor-name--CURSOR--+-----------+------------------>
                                 '-WITH HOLD-'

>--+----------------------------+--FOR--+-select-statement-+---><
   |              .-TO CALLER-. |       '-statement-name---'
   '-WITH RETURN--+-----------+-'
                  '-TO CLIENT-'
```

Why have you specified SENSITIVE STATIC SCROLL? Is there a specific requirement?

You can specify SENSITIVE STATIC SCROLL only when you are declaring a cursor within a CLI application, in the case of which, the declaration precedes with the EXEC SQL stmt:

```
EXEC SQL DECLARE C2 SENSITIVE STATIC SCROLL CURSOR FOR
  SELECT DEPTNO, DEPTNAME, MGRNO
  FROM DSN8910.DEPT
  ORDER BY DEPTNO
END-EXEC
```

Comment: Yes, i was creating the cursor in SP, Thnx